# SharePoint 2013 how to run JavaScript or jQuery for calendar add event popup window

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, calendar, auto-populate

I have a calendar app created in SharePoint 2013, I want to Autofill Location text field in popup window of add new event.

How can I do it with help of JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to New form page of calendar list form using URL in below format:

   ```
   https://siteUrl/Lists/ListName/newform.aspx
   ```
2. Edit the page
3. Add Script editor/Content editor web part on page
4. Add below code in web part to auto-populate the Location field on form:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function autoPopulateLocation(){
        // your code
        document.querySelector("input[title^='Location']").value = "My custom value";
    }
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("autoPopulateLocation");

</script>

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("autoPopulateLocation");
```

5. Save/Stop Editing the page.

**Output**:

[image]

**Update from comments**:

To disable the textbox, use below code:

```
document.querySelector("input[title^='Location']").disabled = "disabled";
```

OR with `readonly` attribute like:

```
document.querySelector("input[title^='Location']").readOnly = true;
```

Comment: Great, it is working, How can i make it diabled? So users cannot retype

Comment: To disable the textbox, use code given in updated answer.

Comment: Also, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Comment: Sure, I will up vote but i need to signup or need to find login information and sign in. Right now i am i urgent situation, just one more question, your code work fine but i need one more help, after adding the event, it is not taking inforamtion from diabled field and it is coming blank when open or edit it, how can i post data from diable field to the calendar.

Comment: I wonder how you are adding comments here without login :) However, try using `readOnly` approach from updated answer.